# Generic type treated as a value in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

While trying out generics in typescript, I failed miserably with a cryptic error message from typescript.
I tried creating a wrapper to create classes with a common base class, but I'm getting this error:
`'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. ts(2693)`
Here is the code:

```
class Test {
    constructor(i: number) {
        
    }
}

class Test1 extends Test {

}
class Test2 extends Test {

}

function f<T extends Test>(n:number): T {
    return new T(n)
}
```

The following works, but is not generic:

```
function f1(n: number): Test1 {
    return new Test1(n)
}
```

Here's the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=6&module=1&ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgCoFNoBc4G9hx3UB7AOzQCcBXUVfEgCgEsAuOQsgWwCMkSBKTbXAfxwBfYKLBRYiFKgCMcJAA9USQgBN4yNHzESYmmQCYFy1Runasu4ADMyhSnSJwbAHgQmV6g2gB8NQgYWDi5uJg8sARIkVDISQmYkAHdEAO5rOwdUJwSbWQCmYM4ecJl5SNxo2PjElK05NN0gA).

Can someone explain what's going on here, what should I do to fix this?
Also tried creating an interface that defines a required CTOR, but it doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: You cannot call `new T()` because the whole type system only exists at compile time. Not at runtime. The generics and all other types will be stripped away, yet you want to access that ambient context via `new` which is not allowed and not possible.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks, I think I understand that, is there a way to achieve this? and why is `T` treated as a value anyway?

Comment: Because `new T()` would execute at runtime. That's when values exist and you do handle it as if it's a runtime value.

Comment: Also, I'm not really sure it's THAT useful to do this. You can accept a constructor in your function but then the function becomes a useless wrapper: `function f1<T>(n: number, ctor: new (x: number) => T): T { return new ctor(n) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call it that way - generic types define only types and do not exist in javascript.

What you can do is passing your class as another argument

```
function f<T extends Test>(clss: new() => T, n:number): T {
    return new T(n)
}
```

Then the type of the class will be inferred and you can even call it as

```
f(Test2, 2)
```

The result of the function call will be of type `Test2`

Comment: The `new ...` expression can be simplified with `Type` imported from *'@angular/core'*, e.g. `function f<T extends Test>(ctor: Type<T>, n: number): T {` .